# Proving a union of two partitions is a partition of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

My question reads:

Let $A$ be a set with at least three elements. If $P=\{B_1,B_2\}$ is a partition of $A$, $C_1$ is a partition of $B_1$, $C_2$ is a partition of $B_2$, and $B_1$ does not equal $B_2$, prove that $C_1 \cup C_2$ is a partition of $A$.

Would I have to go through this by showing each condition of the definition of a partition is met? So would I have to have something like Let $X$ be in $C_1 \cup C_2$ and go from there? I am not too sure how to set this proof up in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See that $$\begin{align}
   A &= B_1 \cup B_2\\ 
   &= \bigcup_{X\in C_1}X \cup \bigcup_{X\in C_2}X\\
   &= \bigcup_{X\in C_1\cup C_2}X
   \end{align}$$
2. And let $X, Y\in C_1\cup C_2$ such that $X\ne Y$.

Either $X$ and $Y$ are both in $C_1$ (resp $C_2$), and therefore $X\cap Y = \emptyset$ because $C_1$ (resp $C_2$) is a partition.

Or $X\subset B_1$ and $Y\subset B_2$ (or the other way around), and therefore $X\cap Y = \emptyset$ because $P$ is a partition of $A$.

Therefore in any case, $X\cap Y = \emptyset$.

3. Also note that $\forall X\in C_1\cup C_2, X \ne \emptyset$.

This leads $C_1 \cup C_2$ to be a partition of A.

Comment: So we do not need to go through each part of the definition of a partition? wouldn't we first have to have some set in the union and then go from there?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, could you please reformulate ?

Comment: I mean proving a set X is in the partition, then the second condition that X=Y or their intersection is disjoint, and then the last point that is the union over X

Comment: What I did is that I proved that the union was $A$, then that two elements of the partition were disjoint (ie their intersection is $\emptyset$) and finally that none of them is empty. I don't understand what else you would want to prove ?

Comment: Ah, I was confused because in class we go backwards, we start with showing non are empty so I did not really understand it how its written. Also this why I do not really see how we have X as non empty/

Comment: $X$ is either in $C_1$ or $C_2$ and since none of the elements of $C_1$ or $C_2$ are empty (because they are partitions), $X$ is not empty.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, you just used the definition straightforward.  But then how did you show the X,Y in C1 or C2? Aren't you supposed to show either X=Y or they are disjoint? I see you let X not equal Y and went from there.

Comment: I proved for any $X,Y \in C_1 \cap C_2$ that if $X\ne Y$, then $X\cap Y = \emptyset$. This implies that for any $X, Y \in C_1\cup C_2$ either $X=Y$ or they are disjoint.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Sorry this is new to me so I have to take it step by step. For the 1st part you did the union over X but how did you get to that conclusion? Did you use the definition?

Comment: Yes, this is what  I did

Comment: But i dont see this too clearly, Did you start of by picking an element in X for C1? Union is the one where it is there exists not for all correct?

Comment: You could do it like this but it isn't necessary, what I did is absolutely equivalent to what you desfribe btu far less painful to write. See [the wikipedia article on sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations) for more detailed info.

Comment: hmm I understand its less steps but since I am just learning all this I was hoping for a just a bit of detail for this step because unions over a set is where I usually get lost and the definition helps me to remeber how to go about it

Comment: I do not understand your union over X definition. How did you prove A is a subset of the union and the union is a subset of A?